# Using existing template for form(showing not all fields)

Tags: django, django-forms

The issue is next: I'm using existing templates for my site. I have an `order` page. I want to use my own template for form

I know that I can implement it just using `{% for field in form %}`. But I need to show not all fields. For example, here is my `Order` model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    state_choices = ('ACTIVE', 'COMPLETED', 'FROZEN')
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='ACTIVE')
    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
```

I need to show just: `address_city`, `address_street`, `address_building` and `delivery_time`. Because in view I just return current user and set it to client. Here is my view that saves `Order`:

```
def submit(request):
    args = {}
    args['form'] = OrderForm
    if request.POST:
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            order_form.save()
            user = request.user
            address_country = order_form.cleaned_data['address_country']
            address_city = order_form.cleaned_data['address_city']
            address_building = order_form.cleaned_data['address_building']
            delivery_time = order_form.cleaned_data['delivery_time']
            new_order = Order(address_country=address_country,
                              address_city=address_city,
                              address_building=address_building,
                              delivery_date=delivery_time, client=user)
            new_order.save()
            Basket.objects.filter(client=user).delete()
            return redirect('/order/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'order_page.html', args)
```

I guess that `new_order` is odd, because `order_form.save()` saves it. But how to set user of current session to `Order` through `form`?
To understand it all, here is my `OrderForm` code:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Order
        fields = ['address_city', 'address_street', 'address_building', 'delivery_time']
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle this kind of logic in the form's **init** method, and when creating the form in the view I pass in the request object as a kwarg for the form to get its data from, then hide the appropriate fields:

In forms.py...

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if request:
            self.fields['field'].initial = process_request_to_get_value(request)
            self.fields['field'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        # More logic here if needed

    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

In views.py...

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST, request = request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('somewhere')
    else:
        form = YourForm(request = request)
    return render_to_response('template',
        {'form': form,},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: So, it throws an error: clean() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Where are you calling the clean method? The only reason I can think that's happening is because you manually call it and supply parameters. The first parameter in Python is always self, but I don't know what the second would be. Forms automatically call clean when you check is_valid on them.